# Reading text file contents from an S3 bucket using an S3 URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

I need to read the content of text file which is uploaded in the AWS S3 bucket. I have the URL for the file located in S3 bucket. Could someone please help me to read the text file content using the S3 URL.

I know we can read the Data using ResponseStream but would like to read it using the URL / Path. I need to create an AWS Lambda service using .NET Core. Below code highlights how to read it using ResponseStream

```
using (GetObjectResponse response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(requestGet))
using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
```

Comment: Why not use the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) to get the object?

Answer (score 3):

AWS .Net SDK is the answer for your question:

-Execute the getObject method by providing bucket name and object key in the request.

-Execute one of the GetObjectResponse methods to process the stream.

Below is the sample for the same from AWS [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html):

```
﻿using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class GetObjectTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "*** bucket name ***";
        private const string keyName = "*** object key ***";
        // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
        private static IAmazonS3 client;

        public static void Main()
        {
            client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
            ReadObjectDataAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task ReadObjectDataAsync()
        {
            string responseBody = "";
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"]; // Assume you have "title" as medata added to the object.
                    string contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Object metadata, Title: {0}", title);
                    Console.WriteLine("Content type: {0}", contentType);

                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Now you process the response body.
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code also uses responseStream for reading the bucket. I am aware of this method I want to read the file in S3 bucket by passing the url of the S3 bucket file. Way we read the file by passing the Url in Filestream object. Looking for way if I can pass the path of S3 bucket in StreamReader.

Comment: i am not sure but you afik you will not be able to pass the S3 string to streamreader as source and read the file directly. The reason for this is S3 requires lot of other parameters to open the file via streamreader. I know you can hit the link and the file is opened in your browser with the text - may be you can implement a way to read it via that method and converting the browser call in code then use streamreader. But it looks like too much complications. BTW why you need to pass directly in reader  ? Any specific reasons?

Comment: I need some way to read the file using path or Url as need to convert existing code to Lambda and in that code they are using one parser that reads from the file location not from stream, So I need some way if file can be read by providing the Path of S3 file

Comment: I am sure you would have tried - using lambdawiths3 role along with the copy event  .. which will take the s3 location of bucket and you can define the file which are needed.